# iOS App - Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, nib

I have a Universal iOS app and the iPad version uses an interface called `PerformancePair.xib` which I load in the following way:

```
_pairView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"performPair" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

When that line is executed, I get the following error:

```
       2014-07-25 12:18:17.432 R2Lm[48976:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
        'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 
        'NSBundle </Users/Me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/698D6EC4-2150-492B-9935-96B56FF95AE2/R2Lm.app> (loaded)' 
         with name 'performPair''
            *** First throw call stack:
            (
                0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101e95495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
                1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010199599e objc_exception_throw + 43
                2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101e952ad +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
                3   UIKit                               0x000000010079d742 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 775
            ...MORE STACK TRACE HERE....
```

You can see that I have correctly named the RestorationID with `"performPair"` and that my `PerformancePair.xib` is in my build phase.

[image]

What else am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the name of the nib file in `loadNibNamed:`.

```
_pairView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PerformancePair" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```